# not able to see the controls values from DB in user control when i am access the user control from page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls, postback

I have got one user control, I am loading this user control from a parent page when the button clicked ..

In user control I have got one drop downlist and grid view , both data is loading form DB in page load method ......

but in parent page when I click on the button to load the user control, I am able to see only one drop down with no loaded  values in it(normally it is loaded with values ) and not able to see the grid  view as well ....

and this is my code ..on parent page

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/template.master" AutoEventWireup="true"            CodeFile="ViewCertificateMaster.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages_ViewCertificateMaster" %>

  <%@ Register Src="../Controls/one.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="one" %>
```

and in code behind file

```
protected void btnShow_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectedItem = ddlProductType.SelectedIndex;

    switch (selectedItem)
    {
        case 0:

            UserControl myUsrControl = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("../Controls/one.ascx");
            divViewMyCerts.Controls.Add(myUsrControl);
            divViewMyCerts.Visible = true;

            break;
     ....................
         ..................
      ..................
       code
```

in one.ascx code behind file ...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string remoteUser = ((UserInfo)Session["USER_INFO"]).GetUserEmail();
    intAcctId = ((UserInfo)Session["USER_INFO"]).GetUserAcctId();
    objCert = new Certificate();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         .............
         here I am binding the grid view and drop down list values from DB
         ...............
         ...............
```

Would any one please help on this why I am getting empty dropdown list and not able to see the grid view as well ....

many thanks in advance

Comment: When you debug the code do you get the object value in this **myUsrControl** variable ?? I guess your user control not loaded in the page.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana I am able to get the object in myUsrControl page

Comment: Have you removed the Ispostback condition from your user control as Priyank said in his answer ??

Answer (score 0):

Because IsPostBack will be true in Page_Load of the one.ascx. Since the control is being added at btnShow_OnClick event at the page and the IsPostBack is true here. Check the value of IsPostBack  in one.ascx in your code.

See the definition of IsPostBack of a user control. Which is

"Summary:
             Gets a value indicating whether the user control is being loaded in response
             to a client postback, or if it is being loaded and accessed for the first
             time.

Returns:
             true if the user control is being loaded in response to a client postback;
             otherwise, false."

Comment: You can modify the if condition from !IsPostBack to IsPostBack.Or you can remove the condition.You can check the state of the drop down and gridview. If they are already bounded then don't bind and if they are not bounded then bind.